# Why >>> eval "$(docker-machine env default)" in a ansible playbook script return "No such file or directory"

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-machine

I try to execute docker-compose for create containers on a **docker-machine** (driver virtualbox) with ansible. So, I write a **ansible-playbook** script to do that. My user (ALL/nopasswd) was added to suddoers group.

Activate the machine before.

```
shell: eval "$(docker-machine env default)"


shell: docker-compose up -d
```

It didnt activate my remote machine. It stays on my host.

ok: [192.168.0.12] => {
    "msg": ""
}

So, docker-compose create container on local machine instead of my remote machine.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Olivier

Comment: First of all `command` module doesn't process shell tricks, use `shell` module instead.

Comment: I change the content of  my question (command to shell) because I was try many operations. I also test shell. You are right but also with shell I can't target my remote machine.

Answer (score 2):

My bad, each task is in a isolated shell, so I write a shell multiline to resole my problem.

```
shell: |
  eval $(sudo docker-machine env default)
  docker-compose up -d
```